# How is the supremum of a power series defined?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, supremum-and-infimum

Say we have a complex function $f(z)$ which can be represented by a power series as $f(z)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_n(z-z_0)^n.$ for $|z-z_0|<R$

Then what does it mean to say that $M(r)=sup\{f(z):|z-z_0|=r\}$ where $0<r<R$.

I understand what a supremum means in terms of a set ( i.e. the smallest upper bound of a set)

But I'm confused as to how exactly it's applicable to power series.

Is it something like $a_0$ is the first element of the set, $a_1(z-z_0)$ is the second entry in the set etc. ?

Or is it that $a_o$is the first element of the set and $a_0+a_1(z-z_0)$ is the second entry of the set ?

Comment: What does that mean? It's  meaningless. Have you actually seen exactly that notation? I hope not. Should be $M(r)=\sup\{|f(z)|:|z-a|=r\}$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich That's the notation we use in class :/

Comment: Could be -- I hope not. It's _possible_ that you just didn't notice the difference between $\{|f(x)|:|z-a|=r\}$ and $\{f(z):|z-a|=r\}$. The first is a bounded set of real numbers, so  it has a sup; the second is a set of complex numbers, so it doesn't have a sup, since the complex numbers are not ordered.

Comment: This is what we were told in class $$Theorem: suppose f(z)=\sum_n={0}^{\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n$$                                                                                              for $|z-z_0|<R$ where R is the Roc. Then $a_n=\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{C(z_0,r)}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz$ for any $$0<r<R$$. Then afterwards we recieved a corollary which went : suppose $f(z)=\sum a_n(z-z_0)^n R>0$ for$$ 0<r<R$$ let $$M(r)=sup\{f(z):|z-z_0|=r\}$$ Then $$|M(r)| >=|a_n|r^n$$ for each n

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich sometimes I do have errors in my notes, because I find the writing hard to read. I put up the theorem and corollary that raised this question for me in the first place just in case.

Comment: If there is a mistake in what I took down, i'd be very greatful if you spotted it.

Comment: ??? I already told you the expression $\sup\{f(z):|z-a|=r\}$ is meaningless. I can't tell whether the error was on the board or introduced when you were taking notes...

Comment: And "the supremum of a power series" is also wrong, is the supremum of the set of (positive) real numbers $\{|f(z)|:|z-a|=r\}$. Being $f(z) = $ a power series is irrelevant (but important foe the result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, less is required. Being $M$ s.t. $|f(z)|\le r$ for $|z - a| = r$ is enough. Using the [ML inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma):
$$|a_n| =
\left|\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{C(z_0,r)}\frac{f(z)}{(z - z_0)^{n+1}}dz\right|\le\frac1{2 \pi}\frac{M}{r^{n+1}}
2\pi r=\cdots$$